# why is Mu-metal in transformers?

Tags: transformer

I know it's used for shielding against magnetic fields but for my homework, it's asking for a diagram and I can't seem to find where the mu-metal is actually used on the transformer

Comment: I would think it's used as a kind of shielding to reduce stray or leakage flux? You would want someone else to confirm that though.

Comment: It won't always be shown on a schematic. You'll need to find an assembly diagram, probably from an audio transformer mfg like Sowter ( https://www.sowter.co.uk/ ). For a mic transformer, it keeps flux out. On line level signals, it keeps flux in - and out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Magnetic shielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding#Magnetic_shielding) works by "conducting" magnetic [lines of force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line) around the thing to be shielded.

[image]

Mu-metal has an unusually high [magnetic permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)), which makes the lines of force tend to want to stay within the material.

If you want to keep magnetic fields either in a small space, or out of a small space, you can shield it by building a box of mu-metal around the space.

---

Afterthought:

The drawing* is not entirely honest: It should show *a few* flux lines going through the shielded space, but the density of flux lines within the shielded space is less than the density outside.  How much less depends on the thickness of the shield material.

---

*It's not my drawing; I stole it.

Answer (score 0):

Most transformers don’t have any mu-metal at all.

You might find it on a high-end audio signal transformer, in the form of an [outer can](http://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/SP-310.pdf).

[image]